# How to create a general route for all models?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have a PHP and Javascript project with Yii 1.1, and the problem is with the URL filtering a search after sorting by column in a CRUD in a particular module. It does not allow me to change the search, it maintains the previous values. Reading I found that the solution was in the urlManager:

```
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

How could I form a general rule to take me several modules?

Comment: Are you using CGridView?